# dependency injection with static create method

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a class with a private constructor and a static Create method that returns an instance of the class, what I would like is for Unity to call this method when an instance of the class is requested.

example:

```
public interface IService
{ 
    void MethodA();
}

public class Service: IService
{
    private Service(){}

    public static Service Create() 
    {
        return new Service();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "requested"? Can you tell more about your needs?

Comment: Let's say I then have a class that has a dependency on IService, I want Unity to call the static Create method to resolve the dependency.

Comment: You can't call a static method while you don't know final type of object. And you can't use polymorhism and generics with static. 

I think you need to going another way. You can store binding information (including pointers to factories for each of denpendence) in dictionary. And creating any new instance by using a generic class that find specific factory in dictionary, and call it method to creation new instance.

Zenject (di pluggin for unity) do it with dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

It was actually quite simple, the registration is as follows

```
container.RegisterType<IService,Service>(new InjectionFactory(c => Service.Create()));
```